# How to wrap elements under a GWT HTMLPanel

Tags: gwt

Let's say I create an `HTMLPanel` with some HTML like:

```
<p>
   Blah blah <span id='1'>more html... </span>
</p>
```

Now I want to attach an event handler to the span. I want to see it as an `InlineHTML` GWT widget.  I tried:

```
HTMLPanel html = new HTMLPanel(stringOfHTML);
parentWidget.add(html);
String id = "1";
Element span = html.getElementById(id);
InlineHTML wid = InlineHTML.wrap(span);  // -- error here
html.addAndReplaceElement(wid, id);
```

The second-to-last line dies with the *AssertionError: A widget that has an existing parent widget may not be added to the detach list*.

Is there a way to wrap sub elements in a `HTMLPanel`?

This is GWT 2.4.

**Note**

After a few comments and answers I realized that I forgot to mention: usually `UiBinder` is the answer here, but I'm not using it because the input is html text created in another context by non-programmers.

Comment: uibinder is your friend.

Comment: Yes, usually it is.  But not in this case, as I'm parsing html/wiki text from users.  It's for advanced users but not programmers, and the uibinder syntax is too verbose and low level.  (I haven't checked, but it's probably not available at runtime either.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not really. You getting this exception because `<span>` element is already a part of some widget.  `wrap` methods can be used only to create widgets on top of elements which are not part of some other widget. If you want to handle clicks on this span, you can add dom handler to the `HTMLPanel`, and then detect which element was clicked.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  Since there is no easy way, with one method call, I ended up parsing the HTML and extracting the parts that I want to make into sub-widgets.  I leave a `<span id='unique-id'></span>` in the `HTMLPanel`, and later call `addAndReplaceElement(widget, uniqueId)`.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `<span>` into an [InlineLabel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/InlineLabel.html) inside your UiBinder template and attach anything you want to it :).

Comment: Yes, this is usually the best way to do this.  I should have specified in my question why I was not using UiBinder.  I will add that to the question.